# Foreach with a if(emtpy) statement

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So I have a site where there are multiple categories, I use foreach to pull the listings from the database. I am trying to display a **Nothing Returned** in the view if the database doesnt have anything to return.

The View

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): { ?>

<?php if(empty($post['title'])){
   echo "Nothing found";
}else{?>

<html> 
<body> 

  <?php echo $post['title'];?>
 <?php echo $post['style'];

 </body>
 </html>                        

        <?php } ?>                       

<?php }endforeach; ?>
```

So it seems to work opposite if I put `if(!empty())`

I am still a little fresh with `CodeIgniter` so sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like so:

```
if (empty($posts)) {
    echo "Nothing returned.";
} else {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        // Display each post
    }
}
```

First try to check if we have anything in `$posts` then try to itarate it with `foreach`.

Comment: This is the most efficient way to do this kind of check.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had to modify it a bit by using if(empty($posts['title']) but it worked, I forgot that even tho I am not looping the database I still am passing data to it that I can check I thought I had to loop first before I could check the data thats why I went below the foreach statement. Anyways thanks...

Answer (score 0):

empty() returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

So, if you want to execute statement echo "Nothing found"; then you must have to use !empty() or alternatively you can use isset() function too. isset() will return True if value is setted to variable.

[see details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `isset()` function with `not(!)` condition

If you are using colon `:` then don't use curly brackets `{}` with `foreach` loop

```
if(isset($posts) && count($posts) > 0){
foreach ($posts as $post){ 

if(!isset($post['title'])){
   echo "Nothing found";
}else{?>

    <html> 
    <body> 

    <?= $post['title'] ?>
    <?= $post['style'] ?>

    </body>
    </html>                        

<?php } } }else{ echo 'No record found';}?>
```

Comment: I tried this already, it does not seem to work as when I click on a category with nothing in it and shows blank, like the same way when I used the if(empty)

Comment: Means `$posts` have no data. First, then apply condition on `$posts`

Answer (score 0):

Just ran your code - you're missing a closing php tag at the end of your 'style' line:

```
<?php echo $post['style']; ?>
```

Alternatively, you could compress things a little as follows:

```
echo "<html><body>";
if(empty($posts)){
        echo "Nothing found";
}else{
    foreach ($posts as $post){
        echo $post['title'];
        echo $post['style'];
    }
}
echo "</body></html>";
```

Comment: You could post a comment to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php if(empty($posts) { 
  echo "Nothing returned."; 
 } else{ 

foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>

    <?php if(empty($post['title'])){
       echo "Nothing found";
    }else{?>

    <html> 
    <body> 

      <?php echo $post['title'];?>
     <?php echo $post['style'];

     </body>
     </html>                        

            <?php } ?>                       

    <?php } } endforeach; ?>
```